# Parsing values from database into ComboBox

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, swing, combobox

Well, I needed to take values from the database, and insert them into the combobox for selection.

Sounds easy enough to do just using 2 classes, **UI class** and **Entity class**, which contains all the SQL queries inside (anything to do with database, it's in there):

```
//This is the UI class

public void fillComboBox(){

    Entity et = new Entity();

    try{
       //call out dbConnector method from Entity class
        conn = et.dbConnector();
        String query="select distinct Name from DbTable order by Name";
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
           //shows topic data in combobox
            comboBoxName.addItem(rs.getString("Name"));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
     //runs method
      fillComboBox();
```

Now, the above output works fine with no hitches. In my form, the combo box displays unique values taken from my database in my specified column.

The problem comes when implementing another tier within it.

In short, I have three classes now.

**Class 1: UI** -> this class purely handles UI

**Class 2: Controller** -> this class purely runs methods

**Class 3: Entity** -> this class purely runs anything that have to do with sql database queries

What I did, was to modify the above code, into this:

This is the UI class:

```
//Declare Variables
JComboBox comboBoxName = new JComboBox();
Controller ct = new Controller();

comboBoxName.addItem(ct.fillComboBox());
```

And a certain method within the Controller class:

```
//Declare Variables
Entity et = new Entity();

public String fillComboBox(){
    return et.takeNames();
}
```

Lastly, my Entity class, which contains all sql queries within.

```
//Declare all variables first
Connection conn = null;
String task = null, names = null;
String query;

//This method connects to database
//There's nothing wrong with this method, I just placed it here to give a general overview of what this method exactly is for you to understand, as I will be calling it out later. Yes, I removed off the **URL** portion intentionally.
public static Connection dbConnector(){     
    try{
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:URL");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connected!");
        return conn;
    }

    catch(Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        return null;
    }
}

public String takeNames(){

        try{
            conn = dbConnector();
            query = "select distinct Name from DbTable order by Name";
            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){
                //shows Name data in combobox
                 names = rs.getString("Name");
            }               
            pst.close();                
        }

        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return names;
      }
```

Well, basically, how this "new" implementation runs is that, the **UI class** calls out the **Controller class**, which calls out the **Entity class**, which runs the method inside and parse back values all the way to UI.

This method is useful in the sense that it separates different portions of a program, making it look neater. Too bad it is a headache to implement. >.>

Now, the error in this would be that, it will retrieve only 1 value, instead of multiple values. What it does retrieve is the very first 'distinct' value in that particular column I specified. The remaining 'distinct' values are ignored.

I have a hunch it had everything to do with the rs setting, @:

```
 ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

What I had in mind was that it only takes 1 value and sets it, then ignores the rest. Does anyone have any solutions for this? I tried arraylist but failed on how to store numerous rs values in the arraylist (this really stumped me >.>)

I do apologize for the lengthy post, but I tried my best to do up till what I can,  before I got stuck at this part for hours.....

Comment: Can you just do something like insert some image of problem your facing at top. It's a wall of text there buddy. And the sooner people get a grasp of the problem the more likely you'll get an answer. A picture is worth 1000 words and all!

Comment: that particular column I specified - be specific....

Comment: Coders don't need a running commentary how you wrote your app. They just need to see the code as it now stands. They can understand the code. If you supply table(s) of sample data and what you get vs what you want that will clarify things!

Comment: Well, the comments are basically not for me, it's what my lecturers expect me to have =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify takeNames() as follows

```
public ArrayList<String> takeNames(){
        //This will collect all names from db
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

        try{
            conn = dbConnector();
            query = "select distinct Name from DbTable order by Name";
            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){
                //shows Name data in combobox
                //Add data to the array list
                 names.add(rs.getString("Name"));
            }               
            pst.close();                
        }

        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Return the array list you created
        return names;
      }
```

Modify fillComboBox() as follows

```
public ArrayList<String> fillComboBox(){
    return et.takeNames();
}
```

And modify the rest as follows

```
JComboBox comboBoxName = new JComboBox();
Controller ct = new Controller();
ArrayList<String> nameList = ct.fillComboBox();

for(String name : nameList){
    comboBoxName.addItem(name);        
}
```

Comment: Declaring an array in the UI and storing it within, huh. Neat idea! This worked, thanks!

Comment: oh sorry! I have no idea that I have to do that. Sorry again for the late doing!